# Can you give me the codes to display the months which have 5 weekends on vb console?

Tags: vb.net

Hey guys i really need help on this. I really have no idea on how to work this out. Can you give me the codes to display it? that would be really helpful

thank you

Comment: For you to know, we are not a code writing service. Please read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you display the months which consist of 5 weekends in a specific year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332715/how-can-you-display-the-months-which-consist-of-5-weekends-in-a-specific-year)  Dont repost over and over within hours of each other.  See also: [Ask]  **that** would be really helpful

Comment: In addition to the other good advice you have been given, please tell us exactly what you mean by 5 weekends in a month. Does it mean 5 Fridays, 5 Saturdays, 5 Sundays, 5 complete Friday to Sunday weekends, 5 complete Saturday to Sunday weekends? Pick **one** of those alternatives or describe a different one.

Comment: you can use this link(http://dotnetdud.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-get-number-of-sundayssaturdays.html) ......i hope this help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: (displays results assuming Sunday is the only weekend day)

```
Sub Main()
    Dim totaldays As Integer = 0
    Dim mnts As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)

    For m As Integer = 1 To 12
        totaldays += Date.DaysInMonth(Now.Year, m)
        mnts.Add(0)
    Next

    For i As Integer = 1 To totaldays
        Dim md As Date = New Date(Now.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddDays(i - 1)
        If md.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
            mnts(md.Month - 1) += 1
        End If
    Next
    For item As Integer = 0 To 11
        Console.WriteLine("Month : " & (item + 1).ToString & " , WeekEnd Count : " & mnts(item))
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much and what year did you put in this code actually?

Comment: @jstellar as you can see "Now.Year" gets the year from your computer's date. Do you want to assign year manually? If so, I can modify my answer ;)